# Robot Framework- How to read particular cell data in xlsx file

Tags: selenium, automation, robotframework

I am new to Python and Robot framework and want to read particular cell data for automation. I have used `Library ExcelLibrary and used a command

```
 Read Cell Data By Coordinates    {Path to excel file}/test.xlsx    1    1
```

but error message appears i.e.

```
FAIL : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Using this in ride robot framework. Please let me know if any other information required.

Comment: Can you post your Python and RF source code? Other tracecalls could be useful also.

Comment: It's seem your Keyword use not correctly . Please check  instruction keyword ExcelLibrary
http://navinet.github.io/robotframework-excellibrary/ExcelLibrary-KeywordDocumentation.html#Read%20Cell%20Data%20By%20Coordinates

Answer (score 1):

Anyway you can use below code if you want to read data from your xls file .

```
${data}    Read Cell Data By Name    Sheet1    A1
```

OR

```
${data}  Read Cell Data By Coordinates   Sheet1    1   1
```

Uses the column and row to return the data from that cell.

Arguments:

> Sheet Name (string)   The selected sheet that the cell value will be
>   returned from. Column (int)   The column integer value that the cell
>   value will be returned from. Row (int)    The row integer value that the
>   cell value will be returned from.